# OpenMP, nested loops design strategy

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, nested-loops

Assuming you have designed a sequential program with nested for loops and would like to transform it to parallel with OpenMP, and work on it in sections to debug as you go... would it be better to work on the outermost loop first and work your way in, or start at the innermost loop(s)? I am aware of the collapse function, but not all nested loops are collapsable.

Comment: This is a rather broad question. There are many factors that play into a recommendation. Can you narrow it down by providing some details beond a generic nested loop, most preferably in form of actual code.

Comment: BTW: I would say as outer as possible, as inner as necessary. But I wouldn't consider that a useful answer.

Comment: Some nested-loops which can't be collapsed with the `collapse` clause can still be collapsed by hand e.g. triangular loops. It's useful to learn how to collapse loops by hand anyway.

Comment: You really should provide some examples in code.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely and definitely ***not*** in the innermost loop. This is because starting threads is generally expensive.

On the other hand, if the innermost loop takes much more resources to execute than starting a thread, then it doesn't make a difference. but otherwise, outermost loop is always the best choice.

Of course, this is a very broad answer in tone with your very broad question. There are always different answers for every different special case.

On the other hand, if you have such a complicated problem, I recommend that you use the low-level `std::thread` and control your threads manually. That needs more work, but you have more control and best results. Then you can use thread pools and have the most efficient solution.

Comment: This is a very thoughtful and detailed answer (for, yes, a broad question. At the time of making it I had in mind a problem of traversing/parsing around a 2D matrix, but intentionally left this bit of info out because I was curious of the general mechanics and problem solving method rather than an answer to my specific problem, which I would have inevitably gotten if I posted it). Thank you.

Comment: Matrices should be stored as 1 dimensional vectors. That's the most efficient way to do it. Consider learning how to use high-performance libraries such as OpenBLAS (or wrappers of these, such as Armadillo). You shouldn't be reinventing the wheel. Matrix operations is a huge field.

Comment: I'm in classes right now, and typically we are supposed to only use certain libraries for certain projects. 2D vectors are fine for this assignment (and what we were instructed to use)

Comment: Homework world and real world are very different. Good luck!

Comment: A thread pool is created de facto with OpenMP implementations so that the threads are not created and destroyed between parallel regions. This means the overhead of using parallel in the inner loop is small (but not necessarily insignificant).